# Iphone programming: remove bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm not sure what it is called, but there is a bar at the top of the iphone screen with the time and battery. What is the simplest way to remove it?

Answer (score 53):

In your Info.plist file, set UIStatusBarHidden to true. Also, you might have to add this in your app delegate:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```

As a reminder, you might have to change the height in your NIB file since the bar is hidden. It might not change it automatically.

Comment: as a reminder, you might have to change the height in your NIB file since the bar is hidden. It might not change it automatically.

Comment: if you want your app to programatically display and hide the status bar at different times, similar to many apps out there, is this object/method the best way to do so?

Comment: @BookOfZeus your comment should be in your answer

Answer (score 8):

Go to your **applicationDidFinishLaunching:** in you app delegate and write this code..

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```